# Latex, RenderTable in Shiny, R

Tags: r, latex, shiny

I just trying to get `$\10^{-1}$` in a table in Shiny, but it is not working. I'm trying the following code (thanks in advance):

**ui.R**:

```
require(shiny)  
shinyUI(tableOutput('mytable') 
)
```

**server.R**:

```
  require(shiny)  
shinyServer(function(input, output){  
output$mytable <- renderTable({  
df <- data.frame(A = c("$\\10^{-1}$", 33.1, 6),B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233))  
df  
  }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mathJAX in shiny:

```
require(shiny)  
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    withMathJax()
    , h2("$$\\mbox{My Math example }\\sqrt{2}$$")
    , tableOutput('mytable')
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){  
  output$mytable <- renderTable({  
    df <- data.frame(A = c(HTML("$$\\alpha+\\beta$$"), 33.1, 6),B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233))  
    df  
  }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you jdharrison! I just realized that I was using R-studio browser, and that cause the problem!

Comment: @user150272 if this answers your question please consider marking the question as answered by placing a tick.