# Manually changing Shiny table column names to Latex formatting

Tags: r, shiny

I'm relatively new to Shiny. I have a table which has inherited its column names from the data in the table. Is it possible to now manually change the table's column names to other names with Latex formatting?

Here's how I've created the table in `server.R`:

```
output$table1=renderTable({data1},digits=6,align='c',bordered=TRUE)
```

Comment: Not sure how Shiny would render latex formatting. But you can always do: 
`output$table1=renderTable({ 
names(data1)<-YOUR_COLUMN_NAMES 

data1 },digits=6,align='c',bordered=TRUE)` In fact you can write more  codewithin the `renderTable` function, just be sure to return `data1` at the end.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620221/latex-rendertable-in-shiny-r) help?

Comment: @user5029763 Thanks for that. I think that partially helps. However, I'm trying to get the column names to be latex, not the table values and I can't seem to get that to happen. Is there an easy fix using the method in your link?